# Run node command take so much time

Tags: node.js, macos

```
system:macos 10.13.6
shell: zsh or bash
node: 10.12.0
```

In my terminal run : `time node -v`

```
real    0m10.197s
user    0m0.006s
sys 0m0.007s
```

I use `time /Users/luxueyan/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/bin/node -v`,the result is the same. The real time is 10s.

Comment: node version 10.12.0 seems a little old, maybe you should install a newer version.

Comment: not only node.Other command also run delay. After a few seconds, it really run